# How do I use Objective-C libraries in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-x

We've created several libraries in Objective-C in the past, and now we're moving to the [Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) game engine. We can't figure out how to reference and use those libraries (we've also tried compiling them as Objective-C++ libraries).

How can we reference and use those libraries in Cocos2d-x?